# How to render a normal view file using "render" method in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have 2 view files, `index.html.erb` and `index.js.erb`. The erb file obviously contains all the data to be sent to the `yield` call.

Now I want to insert the content of `index.html.erb` into `#contents` div on the page, using `index.js.erb`.

Is there a way to render index erb file into a variable in the js.erb file, so I can send it to the client? Currently I'm having to create a partial which contains the complete html.erb file, and calling that from both the main views.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your index.js.erb (here example for `post` resource):

```
<%= render template: "posts/index.html" %>
<%= render template: "posts/index.html" layout: false %>
```

[Using render](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render) is quite good described in rails guides.

Comment: Yes! Just found it when searching for code (file: ""). Do you know if there's any difference between file: and template: ? Both work the same for me.

Comment: Actually with template: you get content-type 'text/html' by default and with file: you can specify any including custom.